# Can't start developing for android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app on iOS and now I need an android version. I downloaded android studio, downloaded everything from SDK manager, did everything for a basic project. But Everything I use is deprecated. Tried making tabbed application. ActionBarActivity deprecated, every other thing I try is deprecated. How can you start doing anything on android, when a tutorial made one month ago is already deprecated? Can someone help me out and tell a good source that has a tutorials or something that works?

Comment: Use Latest Version then....

Comment: Android studio shows that 1% of users will be reached. Not what i want.

Comment: It all starts with **reading**. For example, reading the 2 minutes tour that explains why this type of question if considered off-topic here. Or reading the developers blog. Or reading a full book on Android development. Reading FTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Start with studio**

When starting with studio will be confusing but don't worry I think this may help you

1. Start a project
2. Writing a layout first decide the layout for the app for scrollable apps use
3. Writing java this is main part here you can do wherever you want to do with your app (PS: search on net what you want you mostly find it you can use
4. Modifying AndroidManifest.xml to add permission
5. Compile and run the app for creating a apk go to Build>>Generate signed apk
6. Test app with logcat running so you can see what's happening behind
7. Distributing the app through play store

Useful Links:

1. [Proguard (obfuscation of app)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)
2. [Android Assets Studio (making different size of picture )](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

   3.[Android Arsenal (for library)](https://android-arsenal.com/free)

   4.[Graphics cheat sheet](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/)